# Применение спецификация MOF (Meta-Object Facility) OMG к архитектуре метамоделирования

Tags: model

OMG разработал стандарт [MOF](http://www.omg.org/mof/).  С другой стороны есть такое понятие как "[Metamodeling architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-Object_Facility#Metamodeling_architecture)"

Как элементы стандарта отображаются на архитектуру? При исследовании этого вопроса возникли следующие варианты ответов (гипотезы):

1. Объекты MOF полностью являются объектами M3 и никак прямо не участвуют в других уровнях архитектуры (т.е. CMOF полная спецификация элементов M3).
2. Часть объектов MOF относятся к M3, а часть к M2 и ниже (Например EMOF - M3, а дополнение до CMOF к M2).
3. Объекты MOF только инструмент для создания моделей M3 и трансформации этой модели на M2. Тогда есть модель M3 на которой разработан UML2
4. Это вообще никак нельзя отображать.